# Array of TImage (Delphi Android)

Tags: delphi

```
procedure TForm1.controlClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 2 to Dest.Count-1 do
  begin
    img[i-2].Create(Form1);
    with img[i-2] do begin
      Parent:= Panel1;
      Width:= 100;
      Height:= 150;
      Top:= 10;
      Left:= (i-2)*100;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

img type is array of TImage, control is a tab. I want to timages to show like an android gallery. But this gives me an error Access Violation.

Comment: where do you define the size of the array?

Comment: Your `img[i-2]` is uninitialized.

Comment: @JamesBarrass i defined like img: array of TImage; ( i tried to create dynamic size)

Comment: you need to call SetLength on it prior to using it to define its size.

Comment: img.SetLength(Dest.Count); ? @JamesBarrass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the classic error in creating an object. Instead of

```
obj.Create;
```

you must write:

```
obj := TSomeClass.Create;
```

In your case you need to first of all allocate the array:

```
SetLength(img, Dest.Count-2);
```

And then in the loop you write:

```
img[i-2] := TImage.Create(Form1);
```

to instantiate the images.

Comment: oh ok, i use flowlayout. Thank you david. :)

Comment: how can i add click event?

Comment: That sounds like a new question. We can't really answer new questions in comments.